# Spawning instances of non-static classes in Java

Tags: java

I have the following classes:

```
public class MyClass {

   public static void callFromThirdPartyApp(String allInput){
      HideInput hi = new HideInput();
      hi.workWithInput(allInput);
   }
}

public class HideInput {
   public void workWithInput{String allInp)

   work with allInp...
}
```

What I would like to achieve is that whenever the `callFromThirdPartyApp` method is called it will take the input, initiate a non-static class, pass all input to the class and let it work with it.

The challenge is that `callFromThirdPartyApp` can be called simultaneously. Will this code kick off different instances of the `HideInput` class that will make sure the `allInp` cannot be touched by other instances of the class?

EDIT1: indentation 
EDIT2: sorry I meant non-static, instead of private
EDIT3: amended title to non-static (from private)

Comment: I tried to correct the indentation of the code sample, but there are so many missing brackets and parentheses that I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to show. And I don't see any private classes at all.

Comment: Are you asking if callFromThirdPartyApp creates each time new instance of HideInput? Yes it does.

Comment: I don't see anything private about these classes. Every time `callFromThirdPartyApp` is called, a new object `HideInput` is made.

Comment: I amended identation and also I also meant to say non-static class (for HideInput)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, access to allInp will be safe from unwanted access due to following reasons.

1. New instance of HideInput is being create in each invocation of callFromThirdPartyApp().
2. allInp is being passed as a parameter to workWithInput().
3. allInp is a String which is an immutable class.

allInp is not only safe against inadvertent sharing of HideInput but also thread safe due to #2 and #3.

Comment: Points 1 and 3 are ok. But what you mean by allnp is being passed as a parameter to workWithInput() (2). This is an empty phrase. 1 and 3 are enough as argument for thread safeness.

Comment: Thanks @sgp15!
Could anyone else confirm as well please?

Comment: @ŁukaszRzeszotarski - I was going by the requirement "allInp cannot be touched by other instances of the class" in addition to thread safety.

Comment: But still it is an empty phrase. How differently can it be passed? :) 1. and 3. are enough. Ad. 1. Because of the fact that each thread produce new instance. Ad. 3. Because String is immutable. (If we would have had some other mutable object it hadn't been safe (potentially if the same Object would have been passed)). So 1 and 3 are sufficient.

Comment: Consider implementation of HideInput independent of its usage. Had allInp been set with a setter, the caller could modify its value making HideInput as a whole unsafe.